# How to prevent outer Select statement from being generated when using Union?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have something like the following:

```
                var peopleFromPhones = _context.Phones.Where(p => p.PhoneNumber.StartsWith(searchVM.Phone))
                .Join(_context.People,
                    phone => phone.ContactID,
                    person => person.ContactID,
                    (phone, person) => new Person()
                    {
                        FirstName = person.FirstName,
                        LastName = person.LastName
                    })
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        Name = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName
                    })
            ;

            var orgsFromPhones = _context.Phones.Where(p => p.PhoneNumber.StartsWith(searchVM.Phone))
                .Join(_context.Organizations,
                    phone => phone.ContactID,
                    org => org.ContactID,
                    (phone, org) => new Organization()
                    {
                        BusinessName = org.BusinessName
                    })
                    .Select(b => new
                    {
                        Name = b.BusinessName
                    })


        var results = peopleFromPhones.Union(orgsFromPhones) //UNION HERE

        var items = results.Skip(skip).Take(searchVM.Rows).AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x => new SearchContactResultVM()
                            {
                                Name = x.Name
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

But when I look at the generated SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [t].[MemberNumber], [t].[Email], [t].[ContactId], [t].[PersOrgNbr], [t].[Name], [t].[DOB], [t].[SIN]
FROM (
    SELECT [c].[MemberNumber], [c].[Email], [p0].[ContactID] AS [ContactId], [p0].[PersNbr] AS [PersOrgNbr], ([p0].[FirstName] + N' ') + [p0].[LastName] AS [Name], CASE
        WHEN [p0].[DateOfBirth] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [p0].[DateOfBirth])
        ELSE N''
    END AS [DOB], [p0].[SIN]
    FROM [Phones] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN [People] AS [p0] ON [p].[ContactID] = [p0].[ContactID]
    INNER JOIN [Contacts] AS [c] ON [p0].[ContactID] = [c].[ContactID]
    WHERE (@__searchVM_Phone_0 = N'') OR ([p].[PhoneNumber] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([p].[PhoneNumber], LEN(@__searchVM_Phone_0)) = @__searchVM_Phone_0))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [c0].[MemberNumber], [c0].[Email], [o].[ContactID] AS [ContactId], [o].[OrgNbr] AS [PersOrgNbr], [o].[BusinessName] AS [Name], N'' AS [DOB], N'' AS [SIN]
    FROM [Phones] AS [p1]
    INNER JOIN [Organizations] AS [o] ON [p1].[ContactID] = [o].[ContactID]
    INNER JOIN [Contacts] AS [c0] ON [o].[ContactID] = [c0].[ContactID]
    WHERE (@__searchVM_Phone_0 = N'') OR ([p1].[PhoneNumber] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([p1].[PhoneNumber], LEN(@__searchVM_Phone_0)) = @__searchVM_Phone_0))
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[Name]
```

There's an unnecessary surrounding Select statement hampering the performance of the ORDER BY. I found that if I remove the outer Select that the query runs much faster.

Is there any way to prevent Entity Framework from generating this unnecessary Select statement? I believe it's coming from the Union()

Edit: Here's the faster query that I want:

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [c].[MemberNumber], [c].[Email], [p0].[ContactID] AS [ContactId], [p0].[PersNbr] AS [PersOrgNbr], ([p0].[FirstName] + N' ') + [p0].[LastName] AS [Name], CASE
        WHEN [p0].[DateOfBirth] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [p0].[DateOfBirth])
        ELSE N''
    END AS [DOB], [p0].[SIN]
    FROM [Phones] AS [p]
    INNER JOIN [People] AS [p0] ON [p].[ContactID] = [p0].[ContactID]
    INNER JOIN [Contacts] AS [c] ON [p0].[ContactID] = [c].[ContactID]
    WHERE (@__searchVM_Phone_0 = N'') OR ([p].[PhoneNumber] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([p].[PhoneNumber], LEN(@__searchVM_Phone_0)) = @__searchVM_Phone_0))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [c0].[MemberNumber], [c0].[Email], [o].[ContactID] AS [ContactId], [o].[OrgNbr] AS [PersOrgNbr], [o].[BusinessName] AS [Name], N'' AS [DOB], N'' AS [SIN]
    FROM [Phones] AS [p1]
    INNER JOIN [Organizations] AS [o] ON [p1].[ContactID] = [o].[ContactID]
    INNER JOIN [Contacts] AS [c0] ON [o].[ContactID] = [c0].[ContactID]
    WHERE (@__searchVM_Phone_0 = N'') OR ([p1].[PhoneNumber] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([p1].[PhoneNumber], LEN(@__searchVM_Phone_0)) = @__searchVM_Phone_0))
ORDER BY [Name]
```

I tested it in SSMS and it seems to be ordering the result list and not just the second half of the union.

Comment: If you don't have the outer SELECT I am unclear how the query could have a meaningful ORDER BY at all (since it is probably just ordering the second half of the UNION ALL). Can you show the query you _believe_ to be faster, so we can compare?

Comment: Also, please make sure the code in your question actually compiles (it doesn't right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also are you sure that your second query (after edit) is working as expected?

I simplified and replicated the same logic in following SQL:

```
DECLARE @A AS TABLE ([Name] NVARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @B AS TABLE ([Name] NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @A VALUES ('a'), ('c'), ('e'), ('g');
INSERT INTO @B VALUES ('b'), ('d'), ('f'), ('h');

SELECT TOP(3) [Name]
    FROM @A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [NAME]
    FROM @B
ORDER BY [Name]
```

You could assume that the value would be:

```
Name
a
b
c
```

But in fact in returns:

```
Name
a
b
c
d
e
f
h
```

It took top 3 from `@A` then the `UNION ALL` was applied and then there is the sorting, overall it returns 7 rows

Comment: You're right, it is a totally different query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by " unnecessary surrounding Select ".

The outer select is needed for the pagination queries you made with the `results.Skip(skip).Take(searchVM.Rows)` call.

One thing that is unnecessary in this query if the SQL Select part:

`SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [t].[MemberNumber], [t].[Email], [t].[ContactId], [t].[PersOrgNbr], [t].[Name], [t].[DOB], [t].[SIN]`

You don't need the whole result here, you just need to get `[t].[Name]` for you C# `SearchContactResultVM` model.

To get rid of the rest `SELECT` columns, try this code:

```
     var items = results.Skip(skip).Take(searchVM.Rows)
                            .Select(n => n.Name).AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(name => new SearchContactResultVM()
                            {
                                Name = name
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

I got rid of the `.AsEnumerable()` call, so that the `Select` will apply to the SQL query itself

Comment: I tried altering the output query and it turns out that you can apply the pagination + sort directly on the union itself. Also I tried your change and it gives me "Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: I adjusted the `Select`